# Is our vent sewer pipe clogged

Tags: plumbing, sewer

We have a new problem in out 110 yr old house.  Whenever a toilet is flushed sinks gurgle. We recently had a slow running sink and tub on the second floor.  That was well plunged by a plumber.  This seemed to start after.  Possible the vent is clogged?  Or could it be the main sewer pipe as well?

Comment: I'd sure start with the vent pipe.

Comment: Do the first level toilets, bathtubs, or showers gurgle when any (other) toilet is flushed?